# Django queryset grouping

Tags: django, django-queryset

Say I have these pseudo models

```
class Client(models.Model
    name = ...

class Property(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client ...)
    name = ...
    type = ...
    value = ...
```

For example, I have 2 clients. Each have 2 Property records. It is possible for 2 clients to own the same property, but have unique property records as each client may own a different portion of the property (value).

How can I produce a results such that it returns something like:

propertyA, {clientA, value}, {clientB, value}

propertyB, {clientA, value}

where the property is grouped on the name and type of the property?

Many thanks

---

iodb are you suggesting something like this?

```
class Client(models.Model
    name = ...

class Property(models.Model):
    name = ...
    type = ...

class PropertyValue(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client ...)
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property ...)
    value = models.IntegerField(...)
```

Comment: How do you identify that two Property records owned by different clients are the same property? What's the common identifier?

Comment: Hi Daniel. The identifier would be both the property name and the type. Both would need to match.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to add a PropertyValue class with a value-field and two FK's to Client and Property.

Comment: Hi Idob. I have edited my Q to incorporate and question your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your models don't seem appropriate for the data you want to store and the result you want to get. You need to split property and value, so that there is a many-to-many relationship between Property and Client with PropertyValue as the intermediate class.

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = ...
    properties = models.ManyToManyField('Property', through='PropertyValue')

class PropertyValue(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey('Client' ...)
    property = models.ForeignKey('Property'...)
    value = ...

class Property(models.Model):
    name = ...
    type = ...
```

Now you can iterate over Properties and for each one output the value for each client:

```
{% for property in properties %}
    {{ property.name }}
    {% for value in property.propertyvalue_set.all %}
        {{ value.client.name }}
        {{ value.value }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you both. Can I ask why the m2m field is in the Client model and not the PropertyValue model? I'm getting all sorts of import errors trying to implement this as Client and Properties exist in different apps.

Comment: OK, fixed the import errors. Had to use 'myapp.Property', thorugh='myapp.PropertyValue'